# Very large look up table C++ - can I avoid typing the whole thing out?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, lookup

I am not a programmer, but am an engineer who needs to use C++ coding on this occasion, so sorry if this question is a little basic.

I need to use a look up table as I have some highly non-linear dynamics going on that I need to model.  It consists of literally 1000 paired values, from a pair of (0.022815, 0.7) up to (6.9453, 21.85).

I don't want to have to type all these values out in my C code.  The values are currently stored in Matlab.  Can I read them from a .dat file or something similar?

I will have calculated a value and simply want the program to kick out the paired value.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: perhaps the easiest thing is to print all of those values in a plain text file from Matlab in a format that makes parsing easy, and then read that file from your C++ application.

Comment: If it's static data, copy'n'paste and massage (with perl or your favorite tool) into a source file (header or otherwise). Saves on the typing. Less practical if the data changes often.

Comment: Not closely related to your problem, but you should avoid using floating point numbers as keys to your map.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, I will look into all th eoptions you've given.  As I say, I'm not a programmer so it may take me a while to work out exactly how to implement a lot of the solutions, but that's fine, it's just part of the learning process!

Answer (score 6):

You can't read something stored in Matlab directly, unless you want to
write a parser for whatever format Matlab stores its data in.  I'm not
familiar with Matlab, but I would be very surprised if it didn't have a
function to output this data to a file, in some text format, which you
could read and parse.

Assuming this is constant data, if it could output something along the
lines of:

```
{ 0.022815, 0.7 },
       ...
{ 6.9453, 21.85 },
```

you could include it as the initializer of a table in C++.  (It may look
strange to have a `#include` in the middle of a variable definition, but
it's perfectly legal, and in such cases, perfectly justified.)  Or just
copy/paste it into your C++ program.

If you can't get exactly this format directly, it should be trivial to
write a small script that would convert whatever format you get into
this format.

Comment: Typing in data (even if it is constant) from MATLAB into C/C++ is not the way it is supposed to be done! MATLAB has an extensive set of build-in tools for file I/O, so you can write data in any format you want. I would suggest using the fopen() and fprintf() commands (like [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html)) in MATLAB to dump the data to a file, and then simply read it with your C/C++ code (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596128/how-to-read-floating-number-from-txt-file-in-c)).

Answer (score 1):

this program defines a map, then reading from a.txt file, inserting to a map, iterating on map for any purposes you have, and finally writing the map into a file.
just a simple practice:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream inFile("a.txt", ios::in);

    if (! inFile ){ 
        cout<<"unabl to open";
        return 0;
    }

    //reading a file and inserting in a map
    map<double,double> mymap;
    double a,b;
    while( ! inFile.eof()  ){
         inFile>>a>>b;
         mymap.insert ( a,b );
    }
    inFile.close(); //be sure to close the file

     //iterating on map
     map<double,double>::iterator it;
     for ( it=mymap.begin() ; it != mymap.end(); it++ ){
          // (*it).first  
          // (*it).second 
     }

     //writing the map into a file
     ofstream outFile;
     outFile.open ("a.txt", ios::out); // or ios::app if you want to append 

     for ( it=mymap.begin() ; it != mymap.end(); it++ ){
        outFile << (*it).first << " - " << (*it).second << endl; //what ever!
     }

     outFile.close();
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do for this is as follows as I think this is faster than file open and close. First of all create a header file which contains all the data in an array. You could you a "replace all" available in Notepad or so to replace the () braces to { } braces. Later on you could even write a script that makes the header file from the Matlab file

```
>> cat import_data.h
#define TBL_SIZE 4 // In your case it is 1000

const double table[TBL_SIZE][2] =
{
    { 0.022815, 0.7 },
    { 6.9453, 21.85 },
    { 4.666, 565.9},
    { 567.9, 34.6}

};
```

Now in the main program you include this header also for the data

```
>> cat lookup.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "import_data.h"

double lookup(double key)
{
    int i=0;
    for(;i<TBL_SIZE; i++) {
        if(table[i][0] == key)
            return table[i][1];
    }
    return -1; //error
}


int main() {
    printf("1. Value is %f\n", lookup(6.9453));
    printf("2. Value is %f\n", lookup(4.666));
    printf("3. Value is %f\n", lookup(4.6));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read them from the dat file. The question is, what format is the dat file? Once you know that, you want to use:

```
fopen
fread
fclose
```

for C and

```
ifstream
```

for C++ (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

The program still has to get those pairs from the file and load them in memory. You can loop through the lines in the file, parse the pairs and shove them in a std::map.
Something like this:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
...
ifstream infile("yourdatfile.dat");
std::string str;
std::map<double, double> m; //use appropriate type(s)
while(getline(infile, str)){
 //split str by comma or some delimiter and get the key, value
 //put key, value in m
}
//use m
```

Answer (score 0):

For the signal processing toolbox you can export data to C header files 
directly from Matlab(don't know if it's your particular case):

[Matlab export to C header](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/signal/ug/br179zk-93.html)

Or maybe the following article could be of help:

[Exporting/Importing Data To/From MATLAB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5909/Exporting-Importing-Data-To-From-MATLAB)

Answer (score -1):

One of options is to generate the C++ lookup table in matlab. Just write to some text file (lookup.cpp), read table producing C++ source...